# CI/CD pipelines Azure devops automatic merge after deploy release

Tags: git, azure-devops, build-pipeline, azure-pipelines, branch

I have a classic env. setup like following:

I have 2 branches : Develop and Master.

Is there any way in `azure devops` to setup the following **rule:**

1. When a deploy is succeeded on dev environment (defined in the
   release pipeline of azure devops) **------>** create automatically a `pull request` to merge **develop** into **Master**.
2. or the other one: if a `Build` of **develop branch** is succeded **------->**
       create **automatically** a `pull request` to merge **develop into Master**.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few questions so I can better understand your use case:

- How often would this deployment/build of yours be run?
- Will there ever be any changes going into **Master** that do not come from **develop**?

If you plan to run this deploy/build which would create a PR to merge to **Master** for each change in **develop**, then I would recommend to delete the **develop** branch and instead develop directly against **Master**. Configure **Master** with [Branch Policies](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops#build-validation) enabled that would run a gated build (compile/unit test) before the PR can be merged. This is what my team has been doing for a while now with great success. This change in workflow would prevent the need for having a deploy/build which automatically creates a PR.

If you plan to run this deploy/build less frequently than every change, then I would recommend to use the VSTS APIs and a custom scripting task to automatically create a PR. I believe the scripting task would be fairly similar regardless of whether a deploy runs it or the build runs it. The documentation for VSTS APIs is fairly comprehensive, and I use several of them as part of our pipeline workflows (I use PowerShell). Here is documentation to [Create a Pull Request](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0). This would be run as the last task in the deploy/build.

If you plan to merge to **Master** from areas other than the **develop** branch, I just want to call out that the PR which will be automatically created by deploy/build could have conflicts and require manual intervention.

Comment: Would you run any tests more involved than just unit tests in that "Gated Build" that was configured by Branch Policies? Such as some automated browser testing of a deployment? The OPs original scenario didn't move to MASTER until a deployment was successful rather than just a CI build

Answer (score 1):

I would look into Azure Functions. Create a gate trigger and enable azure function after a successful release.

References:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/create-pr-status-server-with-azure-functions?view=azure-devops